# mysql2 Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

When I download the rails application from github
https://github.com/ari/jobsworth
An then give `bundle install` it throws error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After I give the `sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.4'` and it displays like:

```
Fetching: mysql2-0.4.4.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
/usr/bin/ruby2.4 -r ./siteconf20180212-10708-v1q8lj.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/mysql2-0.4.4/gem_make.out
```

After run `bundle install` it throws same error.

Comment: Have you tried below command before bundle
`sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libmysql-ruby shows

Comment: Run this before `sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql` or `sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql2` if you are using `mysql2`
I forgot to add this in 1st comment.

Answer (score 0):

Running these commands worked for me.

```
brew install openssl

bundle config --global build.mysql2 --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"

bundle
```

You can refer to this link for further help https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1005